# How can I determine X resolution from CLI without randr?

Tags: xorg, resolution, xrandr

Does anyone know of a way to determine the current X resolution from the command line, without using randr?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can grep output of `xdpyinfo` or `xwininfo -root` or `xprop -root`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I wound up using "xdpyinfo | grep dimensions"

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if xdpyinfo uses RANDR:

```
xdpyinfo | grep dimensions:
```

This one assumes the root window's size is the resolution:

```
xwininfo -root |egrep 'Width:|Height:'
```